# In-class static member initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, static-members, constant-expression, in-class-initialization

Given

```
struct X {};

constexpr auto x = X{};

struct S {
    static constexpr auto& rx = x;  
};
```

gcc 4.8 says

> error: non-constant in-class initialization invalid for static member 'S::rx'

```
static constexpr auto& rx = x;  
                            ^
```

> error: (an out of class initialization is required)
>
> error: 'S::rx' cannot be initialized by a non-constant expression when being declared

I expect `x` to be a constant expression, suitable for such initialization. Is this a gcc bug? If not, what is going on here?

Comment: Curiously, if you drop `constexpr` from the definition of `x`, then [it compiles](http://ideone.com/bKFihw).

Comment: [clang++3.5 accepts it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5eb10c28a219d04f).

Comment: Please [report a bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/), thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug, and it seems to be [already reported](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57764).

Answer (score 0):

You may do the below instead:

```
struct X {};

const auto x = X{};

struct S {
    static constexpr auto& rx = x;  
};
```